# how to add assign the value and make an addition in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<input name="" type="button" value="300" onclick="document.all.t1.value=this.value" />
<input name="t1" type="text" id="t1"/><br />

<input name="" type="button" value="400" onclick="document.all.t2.value=this.value" />
<input name="t2" type="text"  id="t2"/><br />
<script>
function add(){
    document.getElementById("t3").value = Math.floor(document.getElementById("t1").value) +
                                          Math.floor(document.getElementById("t2").value);
}
</script>

<input name="" type="button" value="add" onclick="add" />
<input name="t3" type="text" id="t3"/>
```

the above code is bad., expect some to correct it. thank you.

when click 300, the 300 vill in the first textbox, the same as 400, then click add button. the third textbox shoew 700

Comment: Where's your `type` parameter for the `<script>` tag?

Comment: What is not working about this?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal [the "type" attribute is pointless](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html).

Comment: @Pointy: That article is all about `<script>` tags with the `src` attribute, where the mime-type of the retrieved script is already provided by the webserver. This inline code is an entirely different beast: for inline code, I couldn't disagree with that page more. It doesn't really explain _why_ or _how_ "the browser knows what to do". What nonsense.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal the "type" attribute is optional in HTML5.  Browsers reliably assume that the contents are JavaScript code.

Comment: @Pointy: Just because it's not necessary doesn't mean you shouldn't do it. What do you lose by explicitly stating what the script is? HTML5 is still new; many older browsers are still widely-used. You lose nothing and potentially gain something. Recommending that people don't do this seems silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "onclick" has to look like this:

```
<input name="" type="button" value="add" onclick="add()" />
```

References to `document.all` won't work in browsers other than Internet Explorer, so you should change those to use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Comment: when i get the value, how to add them. how to write the add() function? thank you. why i use parseInt. it can't work?

Comment: I don't know what that means; you **can** use "parseInt()" if you want to, but calling "Math.floor()" (though a little weird) should work too - all you need to do is make sure the values are treated as numbers for the "+" operator.

Comment: i used this parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value) but no result. thank you

Comment: Have you fixed the "onclick" attribute of the "add" button yet?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to call the function rather than reference it.

That is, use:

```
<input name="" type="button" value="add" onclick="add()" />
                                                    /|\
                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(){
    document.getElementById("t3").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value) +
                                          parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
}
</script>
<input name="" type="button" value="300" onclick="document.getElementById('t1').value=this.value" />
<input name="t1" type="text" id="t1"/><br />

<input name="" type="button" value="400" onclick="document.getElementById('t2').value=this.value" />
<input name="t2" type="text"  id="t2"/><br />

<input name="" type="button" value="add" onclick="add()" />
<input name="t3" type="text" id="t3"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AQYJh/